# db2 change column from null to not null

Tags: db2

Have a Location column in XYZ table in db2, now I want to change to not null and using the below command

**ALTER table xyz ALTER COLUMN LOCATIONID set not null**

But asking to give default value. How to change the command for that

Comment: what db2 version and platform are you using?

Answer (score 1):

As you are making a previously optional column into a mandatory column, if there is already at least one row in the table that contains a NULL in LOCATIONID then Db2 may prevent the alteration (SQL0407N).

If the table has no rows, or if no rows have null in LOCATIONID column, then Db2-LUW will allow the alteration. You may need to REORG the table before/after the alteration in some cases.

If the table already has rows with LOCATIONID null, you must either set these rows LOCATIONID value to some not-null value before doing the alteration, or you must recreate the table.

When recreating the table, consider specifying a default value via 'NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT ...' if that makes sense for the data concerned.